# How to move between HTML pages in onclick event through JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a buttton which has an onclick event, in which the function `move()` is called. The function should move to a different HTML file I've written. I tried using `window.location.href` but it didn't work.
I have this HTML body code in the file from which I want to move (it's called fileFrom):

```
<body>
    <button id="button1" type="button">Quit</button>
    <script src="Main.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this JS code in the Main.js file (Main.html is the file to which I want to move):

```
var button = document.getElementById("button1");
button.setAttribute("onclick", "move();");
function move() {
    window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/User/source/repos/Trivia/Main.html";
}
```

When I press the button, the page doesn't change. How can I fix the problem so that the page does change when pressing the button? Thanks!

Comment: You should not use a absolute path like that. You should use a relative like path `./Trivia/Main.html`

Comment: If any of the answers helped/ answered your question you should mark it as such. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would use a button to go to a other page if you can just use a [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) like:

```html
<a href="./Trivia/Main.html">Other page</a>
```

Otherwhise you can use a [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) such as:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button1");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log('I just moved a page')
window.location.href = "#your-url-here";
});
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="button1" type="button">Quit</button>
    <script src="Main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also note that you should use a relative path like `./Trivia/Main.html` instead of a absolute path like `file:///C:/Users/User/source/repos/Trivia/Main.html`. A absolute path will probably not work on a server. Something more about [paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Give an anchor to your another html file inside the button tag.

Comment: What is an anchor? How can I give it to the button?

Comment: As you notice from the comment of the OP this isn't very clear. This also isn't really an answer or a comment. However if this should be an answer you should at least add some code to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to the page with the anchor tag.

```
<a href="./Trivia/Main.html">Quit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <button id="button1" type="button">Quit</button>
</body>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("button1");
button.setAttribute("onclick", "move();");
function move() {
alert("hi");
window.location.href = "file:///C:/Users/User/source/repos/Trivia/Main.html";
}
</script>
```

If it doesn't work correctly, file:///C:/Users/User/source/repos/Trivia/Main.html
Please check the exact path of.